# Change language conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I try to make a 'change languge system' for my script. I already created my class and everything works fine. My problem is next: if I have URL `index.php?lang=fr` , my website language is changed as long I have `?lang=fr`. If I remove `?lang=fr` from URL, language is changed too back to english. What is wrong in my conditions ?

P.S: $available_langs is an array with en, fr and ro.

```
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ''){
        if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_langs)){ 
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
            $lang = new Language("languages/");
            $lang->setLang($_SESSION['lang']);
        } else {
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
            $lang = new Language("languages/");
            $lang->setLang($_SESSION['lang']);
        }
    } else {
        if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
            $lang = new Language("languages/");
            $lang->setLang($_SESSION['lang']);
        } else {
            $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
            $lang = new Language("languages/");
            $lang->setLang($_SESSION['lang']);      
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your Language class contain a default setting?

Comment: maybe your session doesn't work..

Comment: @Philipp works for sure. I user other SESSIONs too.

Comment: @Perrykipkerrie i have this line, but doesn't matter. It's about file txt, right ? `public function setLang($lang)
    {
        $this->language = file_exists($this->langpack_dir . $lang . ".txt") ? $lang : "en";
        $this->getLanguage();
    }`

Comment: Use print_r($_SESSION) to see whats happening in your session. Have you installed the right language packs for this?, if the langpack does not exist the default (EN) will be chossen

Comment: @Perrykipkerrie, yes ! I choose only correct values with existing file. This is what i get: `Array ( [lang] => en ) `

Comment: Whats the content of $available_langs

Comment: @Perrykipkerrie: `$available_langs = array('en','fr','de','ro'); `

Comment: Everything is normal. As you say that the contents of the lang in the session is 'EN'. Therefore the EN is chosen when there is no lang attribute in the url